# S3 Bucket access denied, even for Administrator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

First, I have full access to all my s3 buckets (I've administrator permission).

after paying with my s3 bucket policy I'm getting a problem that I cannot view or edit anything in my bucket, and getting the "Access Denied" error message.

Comment: how do you try to access S3? from aws cli or from AWS console?

Comment: @Glasnhost from aws console, also from aws cli

Comment: and what is your bucket policy? have you created the bucket yourself?

Comment: @Glasnhost I cannot view/edit the policy, that's is the problem. i played with it today and all of a sudden I have this problem

Comment: Maybe if you're using any IAM role to play with s3 bucket then that role must have a proper policy for that.

Comment: @AchyutVyas i have `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy in my IAM

Comment: @NirBerko I've mentioned about IAM role, not User. So If you're using lambda to call s3 API, and if the role used by your lambda function has no access to S3, then it might give you an **access denied** Error.

Comment: I'm using lambda and I have the full access in the role (I'm didn't understand how lambda is related to the problem that I even cannot delete this bucket)

Comment: It sounds like you may have applied a bucket policy that prevented you from accessing the bucket. You may need to use the AWS account root credentials to correct this, or talk to AWS support, or create a new bucket and make sure you don't apply the same policy to that bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have added a `Deny` rule on a Bucket Policy, which is overriding your Admin permissions. (Yes, it is possible to block access even for Administrators!)

In such a situation:

- Log on as the "root" login (the one using an email address)
- Delete the Bucket Policy

Fortunately, the account's "root" user always has full permissions. This is also why it should be used infrequently and access should be well-protected (eg using Multi-Factor Authentication).

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have s3-bucket-Full-access  in IAM role policies along with you need to setup

1.set Access-Control-list and Bucket Policies  has to be public.

**Bucket policies like below**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy159838074858",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

here i just added read and update access to my s3 bucket in Action  section if you need create and delete access add those actions there.
[image]

Comment: if you mean `AmazonS3FullAccess`, I have this policy, and still cannot edit anything in my bucket.

Comment: Yup..  you already have public access for access control list and bucket policies (if you already have then it will show bucket permission is public)

Comment: yes, but its doesn't help me :( I'm still unable to edit my bucket policy

Comment: sign in to the AWS web console as the root user and edit or delete the bucket policy by clicking the "delete" button within the Bucket Policy Editor.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/#:~:text=To%20edit%20an%20existing%20bucket,%3AGetBucketPolicy%20and%20s3%3APutBucketPolicy.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
aws s3api delete-bucket-policy --bucket s3-bucket-name
```

Or otherwise, enter with root access and modify the policy

Comment: the problem is that I don't have access